# How to Mouseover only a portion of a image and show a table & link to another webpage -HTML (CSS)

Tags: css, html

This is more of a how to question from a beginner.  I'm building a HTML5 Page.  I have a picture that I want to have three mouseover events.  On 1/3 of the image, I want to mouseover with a Yellow Rectangle which will populate information to the right, if you click I need it to be a link. The 2nd (2/3) of the image will be a red mouseover rectangle doing the same thing.  The 3rd (3/3) of the image will be a green mouseover rectangle doing the same thing -populate information on the right, and if you click links to another webpage.

I have no clue how to build a shape over just a portion of the image so I can mouseover.  I'd like to do this in a CSS with a.hover, but I don't know if I can.

Please Help.

Heather

Answer (score 1):

What you do is have a div with your image set as its background then inside the div you place 3 anchors with a width of 33% and different colors on hover. See my example below.

```css
div.picture { 
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px; 
  background-color: cyan;
 background-image: url(/images/picture.png)
   background-size: 100% 100%
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
border: 1px solid black;
}

div.picture a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 33%;
  height: 100%;
}

a.yellow:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}
a.red:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
a.green:hover {
  background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<div class="picture">
  <a class="yellow" href="/link1.html" />
  <a class="red" href="/link2.html" />
  <a class="green" href="/link3.html" />
</div>
```